# Print of Q&A's not able to get all pages.

Tags: support

When i try to print a Q&A page, I recieve only one page of question and one page of each answer for lengthy ones. I'd like to know if there is a way to print lengthy Q&A's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [StackPrinter](http://stackprinter.appspot.com/), choose "Mathematics" from the drop-down menu and enter the Question id. (I'd find it easier if there was a link somewhere on each question page, but maybe that would increase the comsumption of trees too much.)

Comment: hi there, you can add such link on each question page using the StackPrinter Greasemonkey script available [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/77298). If you don't like Greasemonkey, I would go with the handy StackPrinter bookmarklet that you can find on the StackPrinter home page; just drag it to your bookmarks and click it when you want to print some question page. Let me know if it worked :).

Comment: @systempuntoout : Does the same apply to MO ?

Comment: @Raj what do you mean with MO?

Comment: @system: It's [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/).

Comment: @Raj nope I'm sorry, MathOverflow data is not served by the Stack Exchange API used by StackPrinter to render the post.